# Why redux diff says that states are equal even though ther are not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For fun, I decided to write a booking app.
However ran into a problem when I get free rooms and send room data to TabComponent.js for the first time, everything works. But if I try to send the room data to TabComponent.js again, component does not update, but in redux devtools the state has changed. How to solve this problem? For more understanding, see the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Component.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { reservationCheck } from '../../../actions/axiosApi'
import { sendReservationProp } from '../../../actions/propActions'


class Form extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        free_rooms: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            arrival_date: '',
            leaving_date: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.props.reservationCheck(this.state)
    }

    sendFreeRoomPropToBookingTab = free_room => {
        const reservation_prop = Object.assign(this.state, free_room)
        this.props.sendReservationProp(reservation_prop) <--- sending room prop to tabComponent.js
    }

    render() {
        const { arrival_date, leaving_date } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="booking-form-container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="date" name="arrival_date" required onChange={this.handleChange} value={arrival_date} />
                    <input type="date" name="leaving_date" required onChange={this.handleChange} value={leaving_date} />
                    <button value="" type="submit">Find</button>
                </form>
                <div className="reservation-data-result">
                    {this.props.free_rooms.map(free_room => (
                        <div className="reservation-data-result__block" key={free_room.id}>
                            <img src={free_room.main_image} alt="" />
                            <div className="thumbnail-images">
                                {free_room.room_image.map(thumbnailImage => {
                                    const [id, src] = thumbnailImage.split(': ')
                                    return (
                                        <div className="thumbnail-image">
                                            <img src={src} key={parseInt(id, 10)}></img>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <h3>{free_room.name}</h3>
                            <h5>price: {free_room.price}&#36;</h5>
                            <a className="booking-btn">
                                <div className="btn-circle">
                                    <div className="btn-arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                                <span className="btn-text" onClick={() => this.sendFreeRoomPropToBookingTab(free_room)}>Book room</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    free_rooms: state.roomReducer.free_rooms
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { reservationCheck, sendReservationProp })(Form)
```

action.js

```js
import { RESERVATION_PROP } from './types'

export const sendReservationProp = reservation_prop => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: RESERVATION_PROP,
        payload: reservation_prop
    })
}
```

reducer.js

```js
import { GET_ROOM_DATA, RESERVATION_CHECK, RESERVATION_PROP } from '../actions/types'


const initialState = {
    roomData: [],
    free_rooms: [],
    reservation_prop: {},
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ROOM_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                roomData: action.payload
            }
        case RESERVATION_CHECK:
            return {
                ...state,
                free_rooms: action.payload
            }
        case RESERVATION_PROP:
            return {
                ...state,
                reservation_prop: action.payload
            }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

TabComponent.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class BookingTab extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            room: this.props.reservation_prop.room,
            price: this.props.reservation_prop.price,
            arrival_date: this.props.reservation_prop.arrival_date,
            leaving_date: this.props.reservation_prop.leaving_date,
            name: '',
            phone_number: ''
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("SUBMIT!")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="booking-tab">
                <div className="booking-tab-container">
                    <h2>Booking</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <h3>Room: {this.props.reservation_prop.name}</h3>
                        <h5>Price: {this.props.reservation_prop.price}&#36;</h5>
                        <span>Arrival date: {this.props.reservation_prop.arrival_date}</span>
                        <span>Leaving date: {this.props.reservation_prop.leaving_date}</span>
                        <div className="name-input">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="phone-number-input">
                            <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="X (XXX) XXX-XX-XX" />
                        </div>
                        <button>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    reservation_prop: state.roomReducer.reservation_prop
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookingTab)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `const reservation_prop = Object.assign(this.state, free_room)` actually modifies `this.state` and then sets `reservation_prop` to `this.state`.
So as long as `this.state` is not replaced by a completely new state, you will dispatch the same object multiple times and just modify it - which is something redux cannot detect, as `stateBefore === stateAfter` will hold true.

You probably want to do

```js
const reservation_prop = Object.assign({}, this.state, free_room)
```

which creates a new object every time.